# Can one decompose an arbitrary element of a Lie group into a product of exponentials in the prescribed order?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

**Question**.

Let $G$ be a real Lie group of dimension $n$ and let $\mathfrak g$ denote the associated Lie algebra. Assume that the exponential map $\exp\colon \mathfrak g \to G$ is surjective. Let $\{X_1\ldots X_n\}$ be a basis of $\mathfrak g$.

> Is it true that for every $g\in G$ one has $$\tag{1}g=\exp(\theta_1 X_1)\exp(\theta_2X_2)\ldots \exp(\theta_n X_n) $$ for some $(\theta_1\ldots \theta_n)\in\mathbb R^n$?

If not, can you provide a counterexample? Are there some assumptions on $\{X_1\ldots X_n\}$ that make it true?

---

**Motivation**.

Surjectivity of $\exp$ means that, for any $g\in G$, one has $(\phi_1\ldots \phi_n)\in\mathbb R^n$ such that: 
$$\tag{2}
g=\exp(\phi_1X_1+\phi_2X_2+\ldots+\phi_nX_n).$$
If I understand things correctly, the [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) applied to (2) gives the existence of some coefficients $(\theta_1\ldots \theta_n)$ such that 
$$
\tag{3}
g=\exp(\theta_{i_1}X_{i_1})\exp(\theta_{i_2}X_{i_2})\ldots \exp(\theta_{i_n}X_{i_n}).$$ 
The difference between (1) and (3) is that in (1) we require that the exponentials are in the prescribed order.

Comment: The coordinates $\mathbb{R}^n\to G$ determined by (1) are called exponential coordinates of the second kind. At least for simply connected nilpotent Lie groups this is even a diffeomorphism, but I do not know if merely surjectivity of the exponential is sufficient to guarantee surjectivity of these coordinates as well.

Comment: @EeroHakavuori: Thank you very much. I do not know much about those things and your commentary opens up a whole new world to me. Could you please give me a reference? And please consider posting this as an answer, I think it is a useful remark and would gladly upvote it.

Comment: I have the same question and I would greatly appreciate it if someone can answer it!

Comment: Is your question **exactly** the same? @Mr.Gentleman The assumption that $\exp$ is surjective seems to be hard to use.

Comment: @ArcticChar Strictly speaking, it is not exactly the same. My question is perhaps more concrete: suppose $G$ is one of $SO(N)$, $SU(N)$ and $Sp(N)$, can any $g\in G$ be written in the form of (1)?